# What RUU do I need for my HTC phone?

Tags: htc-desire, radio-firmware

I would like to download the RUU for my phone but I can't figure out which one to get. There are several options on sites like shipped-roms.com. Can you help me figure this out?

The phone is a HTC Desire (GSM). Here is some additional information.

```
Android version
2.2

Baseband version
32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27

Build number
2.29.405.2 CL263770 release-keys

Software number
2.29.405.2
```

And here's some info from the HBOOT menu.

```
BRAVO PVT3 SHIP S-ON
HBOOT-0.93.0001
MICROP-051d
TOUCH PANEL-SYNT0101
RADIO-5.11.05.27
```

First of all, do I pick the Bravo or the Desire link at the website? I know that Bravo was the codename of HTC Desire before it was released, but then why are there two categories? And why does it say BRAVO in the HBOOT menu?

Bravo: http://shipped-roms.com/index.php?category=android&model=Bravo

Desire: http://shipped-roms.com/index.php?category=android&model=Desire

If I look at the baseband version in the Desire group I find these two.

```
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_ARA_2.32.415.3_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_157343_signed.exe

RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.14_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_224699_signed.exe
```

What's the difference between ARA and WWE? Is that Arabic and World Wide English? What about European sold devices with Scandinavian (and English) localization?

Also the 2.29.405.14 seems to be a too high number, or highly developed version that may not be available in my region. The highest update number I have been offered to install is 2.29.405.5 and it was 4.82 MB (incremental update?).

There are many more options in the Bravo group. There are special versions for Vodafone and other operator specific versions. My phone is not re-branded and is not locked to any network operator.

The ones that I most likely would need (in the Bravo group) are these two:

```
RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.5_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_159811_signed.exe

RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.2_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_151783_signed.exe
```

Do I really have to match the baseband version and the build number? Can I get a higher build number even if it is a different radio version? Will it work? Is radio version something you can upgrade?...

**Long version short...**

1. Do I have a Desire or a Bravo?
2. Do I have to match the baseband version and the build number?
3. Will the WWE releases include Scandinavian languages or only English?

Comment: Too many questions asked here, the general consensus of this site, is one question per post....

Comment: I believe the name "Bravo" was the "codename" for the HTC Desire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Both.  Bravo is HTC's internal codename name for the Desire.  They do this as they want a constant name for internal purposes as they often sell the identical device in multiple markets under different names (e.g. the HTC Magic is also sold as the HT-03A, the myTouch 3G, and has the codename Sapphire) or multiple devices (e.g. GSM and CDMA versions) under the same name (e.g. both the Marvel (GSM) and the MarvelC (CDMA) are both sold as the Wildfire S).  HTC does it with names, Samsung uses model numbers, same basic idea.
2. No, not unless you want to stay at your current version for some reason.  RUU means ROM Update Utility.  For most purposes, you most likely want to go with the newest not-carrier-specific RUU to have the latest update so you have the latest Android version and radio firmware.  The RUU is the master update-everything.  Android, radio firmware, and h-boot.  It does it all.
3. WWE is World Wide English.  It includes all languages they translate for.  The English bit indicates that English is the base language and all other languages included are translated from English, rather than being written directly in those languages.  The ARA bit indicates the same thing, but that the base language is Arabic.